# Why i can't update image in django?

Tags: python, django

> modle.py

```
class Form(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
email = models.EmailField()
file = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)

class Meta:
    db_table: 'django'  # table name
```

> edit.py

```
<form action="{% url 'update' user.id %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="mb-3">
          <label for="exampleFormControlInput1" class="form-label">Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="name" name="name" value="{{ user.name }}">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
          <label for="exampleFormControlInput" class="form-label">Email address</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput" placeholder="name@example.com" name="email" value="{{  user.email }}">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
          <label for="exampleFormControlInput2" class="form-label">Image</label>
          <input type="file" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput2" name="{{  user.file }}" >
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <img src="{{ user.file.url }}" alt="" srcset="" style="width:100px">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="liveToastBtn">submit</button>
    </form>
```

> view.py
> **when i try to update from all the fields is all update and also remove old image but it doesn't save new image to directory please help me**

```
def update(request, user_id):
user = Form.objects.get(id=user_id)
form = UserForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=user)
if request.method == 'POST':

    if form.is_valid():
        if os.path.exists(user.file.path):
            os.remove(user.file.path)
        form.save()
        return redirect("listing")
    else:  # mean form is invalid
        return render(request, 'edit.html', {'user': user})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `file` tag you have set `name="{{  user.file }}"` replace that with `name="file"` as

```
<input type="file" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput2" name="file">
```

The `name` attributes of your `html` must be according to the `field` name of your model.

Comment: it's working thank you so much❤️❤️

Comment: My pleasure @Oeng Kim Chhay

Comment: @Nikhil Kotiya. HI, Did you got my email?

Answer (score 2):

Error is in this line

```
<input type="file" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput2" name="{{  user.file }}">
```

{{user.file}} is data of user so it only show you data if you want to edit file change

```
   <input type="file" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput2" name="file">
```

Comment: it's working thank you so much❤️❤️